# Prefetch API data (dataGroups) using Angular Service Worker

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have an Angular website that needs to work offline. Part of what it needs is some data from the API. This can be stale data, so my strategy is to try the API, if that fails, then get it from the cache.

I set this up using the `dataGroups`:

```
"dataGroups": [
    {
        "name": "offlineData",
        "urls": [ "/api/offline" ],
        "cacheConfig": {
            "maxSize": 1000,
            "maxAge": "100d",
            "timeout": "500u",
            "strategy": "freshness"
        }
    }
]
```

However, if a user installs the app (using the manifest), and immediately go offline, the API data doesn't exist in the cache as dataGroups doesn't prefetch.

So where is the correct place that I should hook into and fetch the data? I've tried in the `app.component`, and in the ServiceWorker Update Service (which is really the same as the `app.component` as it gets called from there).

Either way, this seems to call the API *before* the service worker configuration has been processed, so it doesn't get added to the cache.

What is the appropriate lifecycle hook to add this to, so that it performans a `prefetch` which the ngsw config will then be aware of?

Comment: did you find a service worker way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the initialization of the app, you can add your data to the **localstorage**.
localstorage stores the data tab wise. That means each tab would have their specific data in the localstorage.

So when the api fails due to network connection. You can use the data stored in the **localstorage**.

Comment: Thanks, Minal. That seems like one solution. I'd hoped to just rely on Service Worker to do this, but it appears it's not an option. Will wait to see if anyone else suggests a SW-solution.

Comment: Please upvote too if it's useful.. so that others can use this